# "That" seems to be omitted.

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, sentence-structure, passive-voice

In the game "XCOM: Enemy Within" there is a guy, whose way of speaking seems to be more appropriate for written language (as it seems to me). In particular, he says such a phrase:

> Intelligence sources indicate a rogue organization, with a separate, misguided agenda, is undermining XCOM field operations.

My question is about grammatical structure of this sentence

- What is "is" referred to? To the word "organization?" If so, then is the word "that" omitted?
- Is such sentence construction used in speech?

Comment: "Is" is the subordinate clause verb whose subject is "a rogue organization with a separate misguided agenda". The subordinate clause is called a content clause, also known as a _that_ clause. The subordinator "that" is omissible in this example.

Comment: What makes you think it's a passive clause?

Comment: @BillJ nothing now. I haven't properly understood the construction of a phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a situation where dashes should have been used instead of commas.

> Intelligence sources indicate a rogue organization--with a separate, misguided agenda--is undermining XCOM field operations.

The entire *with ...* phrase is an appositive, and here you can more clearly see that the subject of *is* is "a rogue organization."

> Is such sentence construction used in speech?

You can use it in speech.  It would actually work better in speech as tonal variation would make it obvious that "with a separate, misguided agenda" is an interruption in the outer sentence.

---

Whether or not *that* appears after *is* can change the meaning of the sentence, and this is because *to be* is a copular verb that is used to link a subject and description.

> Intelligence sources indicate a rogue organization is undermining XCOM field operations.

Some activity is happening right now that is undermining field operations.

> Intelligence sources indicate a rogue organization that is undermining XCOM field operations.

The rogue organization's purpose is undermining operations, but we aren't really commenting necessarily on any current activity.

Comment: As I understand, the idea is that the sources indicate the _undermining of operations_, while if I add a word "that" before "is", the sentence will be focused on the fact that there exists an organization, which is doing something. Is this correct?

Comment: See updates to my answer.

Comment: Got it. Should I says "thanks" in the comments or it is done just by accepting the answer (like on TEX.SE)?

Comment: But @LawrenceC :  appostives are noun phrases, but "with a separate, misguided agenda" is a PP, not an NP. It is a modifier though of the head "organisation".

Comment: You're right ... so is it OK to set off PPs with dashes?

Comment: You could, but I'm not sure what there is to be gained by doing so. With dashes, it would become a 'supplement', not a modifier. A supplement is a separate unit of information, parenthetical or additional.

Comment: @BillJ Seems to me the comma bracket already marks it as a supplement; but mileage varies on punctuation.