# Is it possible to omit the Subject Relative Pronouns in some cases?

Tags: meaning

I have known that grammatically it is impossible to omit Subject Relative Pronouns.

By the way, in the following sentence (Intelligence sources indicate a rogue organization **is** undermining XCOM field operations=Intelligence sources indicate a rogue organization **that** is undermining XCOM field operations), I saw that people said that the sentence with omitting the Subject Relative Pronoun is a right sentence. (Source: ["That" seems to be omitted.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/139252/that-seems-to-be-omitted))

> Intelligence sources indicate a rogue organization **is** undermining
>   XCOM field operations. Some activity is happening right now that is
>   undermining field operations. Intelligence sources indicate a rogue
>   organization **that** is undermining XCOM field operations. The rogue
>   organization's purpose is undermining operations, but we aren't really
>   commenting necessarily on any current activity.

If so, Is it possible to omit the Subject Relative Pronouns in some cases?

If so, does "harmful insects indicate a rogue insect **is** undermining trees" mean "harmful insects indicate a rogue insect **that** is undermining trees" ?

Comment: "a rogue organization that is undermining XCOM field operations" is a noun phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that the subject relative pronoun "that" can't be omitted. However, the example sentence is grammatical; it should be analyzed as omitting the reporting conjunction by using "indicate" to mean "indicate that".

Same meaning with or without reporting conjunction "that":

> Intelligence sources indicate **that** a rogue organization is undermining XCOM field operations.
>   Intelligence sources indicate a rogue organization is undermining XCOM field operations.
>
> Damaged foliage indicates **that** a rogue insect is undermining trees.
>   Damaged foliage indicates a rogue insect is undermining trees.

Slightly different meaning with subject relative pronoun "that". In this case "that" cannot be omitted:

> Intelligence sources indicate a rogue organization **that** is undermining XCOM field operations.
>
> Damaged foliage indicates a rogue insect **that** is undermining trees.

(The comparison with "harmful insects indicate" doesn't quite fit because it uses a different meaning of "indicate". But it also requires a subject relative pronoun which can't be omitted.)

> The term "harmful insect" indicates a rogue insect **that** is undermining trees.
>   *The term "harmful insect" indicates a rogue insect is undermining trees. (incorrect)